# How to access anchor tags in HTML when scraping with VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

Essentially, I'm trying to scrape this web page with about 24 entries (a location and some details about the location) on each page. For each entry, there is a link that takes you to a map location - the address of the link listed in the href just so happens to include the coordinates of this location that I am interested in, so I need to be able to pull that from the website as well. Here's a snippet of the HTML:

`<h3>Drilling Rigs</h3>`
`<div class="listing">`
`<div class="listing_details">`
`<div class="listing_name_loc">`
`<div class="listing_name">`
`AKITA Drilling Ltd. </div>`
`</div>`
`<p class="listing_desc_drilling">`
`Rig: 25<br>`
`Job: 2503232704<br>`
`Operator: Cenovus Energy Inc.<br>`
`Location: 12-04-071-4W4<br>`
`Status: MOVING </p>`
`</div>`
`<div class="listing_buttons">`
`<a href="/drillingrigs/akitadrillingltd.25" class="show-details">Details</a>`
`<a href="/drilling_rigs.php?Keywords=&currentLat=55.12101337&currentLng=-110.56680455&currentZoom=13&isSubmitted=keyword&drid=akitadrillingltd.25">Map View</a>`
`</div>`
`</div>`

See how that link has coordinates in it? I need those.

This is the code I have so far - I can access the listing and pull it but not the href yet:

```
Sub scrape_rig_list()
    Dim browser As InternetExplorer
    Dim page As HTMLDocument
    Dim listing As Object
    Dim listing_buttons As Object
    Dim href As String
'open up riggertalk
    Set browser = New InternetExplorer
    browser.Visible = True
    browser.navigate ("https://riggertalk.com/drilling_rigs_list.php?tStatus_Drilling=1&tStatus_Moving=1&tStatus_Down=0&tStatus_Available=&tStatus_ActiveSR=&tStatus_AvailableSR=&centerLat=53.304621&centerLng=-109.995117&centerZoom=5&isSubmitted=locate&infoContent=")
    Do While browser.Busy: Loop
'define each listing
    Set page = browser.document
    Set listing = page.getElementsByClassName("listing")
    Set listing_buttons = page.getElementsByClassName("listing_buttons")
'grab all of them listed on the page
    For num = 1 To 25
        Cells(num, 1).Value = listing.Item(num - 1).innerText
    Next num

    
    browser.Quit
End Sub
```

Any idea how to make this work? Thank you in advance.

I tried to access the anchor tag by tacking on another getElementByClassName onto listing_buttons like this:

```
Set link = listingbuttons.getelementsbyclassname("a")
```

That didn't work. Honestly at a loss, knowledge of HTML is too rudimentary.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements for the specified class.  Therefore, you'll need to refer to the first element in the collection for both your buttons and links.

```
Dim link As Object
Set link = listing_buttons(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
```

Comment: That did the trick, seems simple in retrospect. Thank you!